# Using JQuery toggleclass to manipulate click transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, toggleclass

I am trying to make a nice transition when clicking a button.
The button is basically a div which triggers a Jquery function. The button consists of some text and a FontAwesome icon.

I want to use JQuery in a way that when I click on the button, the FA icon rapidly changes in size *and back*, so people get some kind of animated confirmation of clicking the button. I created a class with a transition which increases the font-size at least:

```
#keepbtn.clicked {
    font-size:3em;
    opacity:0.8;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;   
}
```

And I tried toggling between classes *using a delay*:

```
$("#keepbtn").toggleClass("clicked").delay(250).toggleClass("clicked");
```

But this does not work; it does not change anything.
However, this works (but does not change it back to original size of course:

```
$("#keepbtn").toggleClass("clicked");
```

Any ideas? I'm rather new to transitions and JQuery so I might be adopting the wrong approach altogether.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for delay() to work on non-animated elements, you have to "queue" operators :

```
$("#keepbtn")
    .toggleClass("clicked")
    .delay(250)
    .queue(function(nxt) {
         $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
         nxt();
    });
```

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot. Also for the explanation.